Does every ring admit a faithful Artinian module?
Let $A$ be a commutative (unital) ring. Does there exist a faithful Artinian $A$-module $M$?
I must admit, I haven't made much progress on this question, so I have very little work to show. Obviously, dropping the faithfulness requirement, one can take $M = A/\mathfrak m$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $A$. I cannot see a way to force faithfulness, for an arbitrary product of residue fields at maximal ideals may not be Artinian.
The dual question for Noetherian modules has a negative answer, that is, if $A$ admits a faithful Noetherian module $M$, then $A$ is a Noetherian ring.
To see this, take any generating set $\{x_1,\dots, x_r\}$ of $M$ as an $A$-module and consider the map $f: A\to M^{\oplus r}$ given by $a\mapsto (ax_1,\dots, ax_r)$. This is injective, for if $a\in\ker f$, then $ax_i = 0$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant r$, whence $aM = 0$, but since $M$ is faithful, $a = 0$. Now, $M^{\oplus r}$, being a direct sum of finitely many Noetherian $A$-modules, is Noetherian. Since $A$ embeds as a submodule of $M$, it must be Noetherian too.

Can you explain the last paragraph? What is the "dual question"? And why for Noetherian rings?

Apologies, I meant Noetherian modules. I'll make the required edits.

Let $$ be a commutative (unital) ring. Does there exist a faithful Artinian $$-module $$?
Not necessarily.

Any Artinian $A$-module is a
finite subdirect product of subdirectly irreducible $A$-modules.

If $R$ is a finite ring, $A=R^{\kappa}$ for some cardinal $\kappa$,
and $M$ is a subdirectly irreducible $A$-module, then $|M|\leq |R|$. (This is proved in Example 2, page 450, of my paper Residual bounds for varieties of modules, Algebra universalis 28 (1991).)


Thus, let $R$ be a nontrivial, finite, commutative ring; let $\kappa$ be infinite; let $A=R^{\kappa}$; and let $M$ be an Artinian $A$-module. $M$ is a finite subdirect product of finite subdirectly ireducible $A$-modules, hence $M$ is finite. On the other hand, $|A|$ is uncountable. In this circumstance it is impossible for $A$ to act faithfully on $M$. (That is, the annihilator of $M$ in $A$, $\textrm{Ann}_A(M)$, has finite index in $A$, hence must be nonzero.)
